# How to use different functoids within an array or vector

Tags: c++, functor, c++98

I have written a small piece of code where I am able to call setter and getter functions packed within a functoid using mem_fun templates.

I now would like to use this approach on top of a class hierarchy where every class might have getter and setter which can be registered as pair within a vector or array to be able to call the getter and setter if needed. GUIObject and GUICompositeObject are example classes out of the described class hierarchy.
The bound_mem_fun_t for the objects have unfortunately different types and thats the reason I don't know how to integrate them into an array/vector of pointers to the functors.

In c++11 I would use std::function. Is there a way to emulate this in c++98?

Because our compiler support only c++98 I cannot use the new features of c++11 or c++14. Also boost is not allowed.

```
#include <functional>

class GUIObject
{
    int m_Alpha;
public:
    void SetAlpha(int a) { m_Alpha = a;};
    int GetAlpha() {return m_Alpha;};
};


class GUICompositeObject: public GUIObject
{
    int m_NumOfChilds;
public:
    void SetNumOfChilds(int NumOfChilds) { m_NumOfChilds = NumOfChilds;};
    int GetNumOfChilds() {return m_NumOfChilds;};
};

template<typename T>
struct bound_mem_fun_t 
{ 
    bound_mem_fun_t(std::mem_fun_t<int, T> GetFunc, std::mem_fun1_t<void, T, int> SetFunc, T* o) :
            m_GetFunc(GetFunc), m_SetFunc(SetFunc), obj(o) { } ;
    int operator()() { return m_GetFunc(obj); } ;
    void operator()(int i) { m_SetFunc(obj, i); } ;
    std::mem_fun_t<int, T> m_GetFunc; 
    std::mem_fun1_t<void, T, int> m_SetFunc; 
    T* obj; 
};


int main()
{
    GUIObject kGUIObject;
    GUICompositeObject kCompObj;

    bound_mem_fun_t<GUIObject> GUIObjectFunc(std::mem_fun(&GUIObject::GetAlpha), std::mem_fun(&GUIObject::SetAlpha), &kGUIObject);
    GUIObjectFunc(17);
    int ii = GUIObjectFunc();

    bound_mem_fun_t<GUICompositeObject> GUICompObjectFunc(std::mem_fun(&GUICompositeObject::GetNumOfChilds), std::mem_fun(&GUICompositeObject::SetNumOfChilds), &kCompObj);
    GUICompObjectFunc(17);
    int iChilds = GUICompObjectFunc();

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the complete solution after @filmors answer:

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class GUIObject
{
    int m_Alpha;
public:
    void SetAlpha(int a) { m_Alpha = a;};
    int GetAlpha() {return m_Alpha;};
};


class GUICompositeObject: public GUIObject
{
    int m_NumOfChilds;
public:
    void SetNumOfChilds(int NumOfChilds) { m_NumOfChilds = NumOfChilds;};
    int GetNumOfChilds() {return m_NumOfChilds;};
};

struct bound_mem_fun_base 
{
    virtual int operator()() =0;
    virtual void operator()(int) =0;
};

template<typename T>
struct bound_mem_fun_t : public bound_mem_fun_base
{ 
    bound_mem_fun_t(std::mem_fun_t<int, T> GetFunc, std::mem_fun1_t<void, T, int> SetFunc, T* o) :
            m_GetFunc(GetFunc), m_SetFunc(SetFunc), obj(o) { } ;
    virtual int operator()() { return m_GetFunc(obj); } ;
    virtual void operator()(int i) { m_SetFunc(obj, i); } ;
    std::mem_fun_t<int, T> m_GetFunc; 
    std::mem_fun1_t<void, T, int> m_SetFunc; 
    T* obj; 
};

template<typename T> bound_mem_fun_t<T>* make_setter(std::mem_fun_t<int, T> GetFunc, std::mem_fun1_t<void, T, int> SetFunc, T* o)
{
    return new bound_mem_fun_t<T> (GetFunc, SetFunc, o);
}

int main()
{
    GUIObject kGUIObject;
    GUICompositeObject kCompObj;

    std::vector<bound_mem_fun_base*> kBoundVector;

    kBoundVector.push_back(new bound_mem_fun_t<GUIObject> (std::mem_fun(&GUIObject::GetAlpha), std::mem_fun(&GUIObject::SetAlpha), &kGUIObject));
    kBoundVector.push_back(new bound_mem_fun_t<GUICompositeObject> (std::mem_fun(&GUICompositeObject::GetNumOfChilds), std::mem_fun(&GUICompositeObject::SetNumOfChilds), &kCompObj));
    kBoundVector.push_back(make_setter<GUIObject> (std::mem_fun(&GUIObject::GetAlpha), std::mem_fun(&GUIObject::SetAlpha), &kGUIObject));
    kBoundVector.push_back(make_setter<GUICompositeObject> (std::mem_fun(&GUICompositeObject::GetNumOfChilds), std::mem_fun(&GUICompositeObject::SetNumOfChilds), &kCompObj));

    for (int i = 0; i < 4 ; i++)
    {
        (*kBoundVector[i])(i*10);
        int res = (*kBoundVector[i])();
        std::cout << "Getter result " << res << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately the make_setter function does not really shorten the creation of the functor. Any ideas will be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give your `bound_mem_fun_t<T>` a common base class and use dynamic dispatch to solve your problem:

```
struct bound_mem_fun_base {
    virtual int operator()() = 0;
    virtual void operator()(int) = 0;
};

template <typename T>
struct bound_mem_fun_t : bound_mem_fun_t ...
```

Then you can keep pointers to `bound_mem_fun_base` in your vector and call the elements as `(*v[0])()`.

Also, TR1 does contain `std::tr1::function`, is that available?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I have tried it out, but somehow maybe i miss something.  
`code` 
        std::vector<bound_mem_fun_base> kBoundVector;

        bound_mem_fun_t<GUIObject> GUIObjectFunc(std::mem_fun(&GUIObject::GetAlpha), std::mem_fun(&GUIObject::SetAlpha), &kGUIObject);
        bound_mem_fun_t<GUICompositeObject> GUICompObjectFunc(std::mem_fun(&GUICompositeObject::GetNumOfChilds), std::mem_fun(&GUICompositeObject::SetNumOfChilds), &kCompObj); `code`  
  
I get bound_mem_fun_base cannot instantiate abstract class...

Comment: Yes, as said, you have to use pointers, i.e. `std::vector<bound_mem_fun_base*> kBoundVector;` and then `kBoundVector.push_back(new bound_mem_fun_t<GUICompositeObject> ...`. For convenience I would also create a template function `make_fancy_setter<T>` that creates a `bound_mem_fun_t<T>` for you.

Comment: Thanks again. I have added above a newer version. It would help me a lot if you can help me again a step further.

Comment: After further reading I have now the complete solution including make function template. Unfortunately the make functions does not shorten the creation of the functor a lot.

Comment: Well, you can drop the template parameter, `make_setter(...)` is enough as `T` can be inferred.

Comment: Also, I think you can get rid of those `std::mem_fun` calls, too, by making the first two arguments either explicit member function pointers or just template arguments.

Comment: The type inference had worked and the proposal of explicit function pointers is clear, too. Can you please give more details about the template arguments?

Answer (score 0):

First a remark on std::function from c++11: That will not solve your problem, because you need an already bounded function pointer. This pointer must be bound to your object. I believe what you need is an own implementation to std::bind.

I started only a very! small Binder class which is hopefully a starting point for your needs. If you need to have template parameter lists in older c++ versions, take a look for `loki`. http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/

As a hint I can give you a short example of what i did:

```
class A
{   
    private:
        int val;
    public:
        A(int i): val(i) {}  
        void Do(int i) { std::cout << "A " << val<< " " << i << std::endl; }
};  

class B
{   
    private:
        int val;
    public:
        B(int i): val(i){}
        void Go(int i) { std::cout << "B " << val << " " << i << std::endl; }
};  

class Base
{   
    public:
        virtual void operator()(int i)=0; 
};  

template <typename T>
class Binder: public Base
{   
    void (T::*fnct)(int);
    T* obj;

    public:
    Binder( void(T::*_fnct)(int), T*_obj):fnct(_fnct),obj(_obj){}  
    void operator()(int i)
    {   
        (obj->*fnct)(i);
    }   

};  

int main()
{   
    A a(100);
    B b(200);

    // c++11 usage for this example
    //std::function<void(int)> af=  std::bind( &A::Do, &a, std::placeholders::_1);
    //af(1);

    // hand crafted solution
    Base* actions[2];

    actions[0]= new Binder<A>( &A::Do, &a);
    actions[1]= new Binder<B>( &B::Go, &b);

    actions[0]->operator()(55);
    actions[1]->operator()(77);

}
```